# Feedback the cheat and fraud of etc eth on twitter. How can i recover my loss?

Tags: cpp-ethereum, ethereum-classic

**Eth and etc arg two great projects. 
As i can't find the etc email, hope you can kindly cc to etc too, thanks.
A few days ago on Twitter to search for the etheric classic, found an account, and read the news every day. About 5 o'clock this afternoon, find out of a message, as shown below (screenshot after the event):**
[image: etc twitter msg]

**Earlier in the message there are a few words that the eth is to open a little limited test time, if you go to the address https://etherscanio.github.io/etherscan.io.html and send 3 eth ,it will be returned 30 eth to you . At the time I thought it was an official classic Ethernet Twitter, i did not think too much, send 3 eth from my eth account 0xa236c36C501e887E85964f2B766113bf3A83A8b5 to the account:**
[image]
[image]
**but i did not receive the back of the transfer, it is estimated fooled. Back to Twitter, I saw part of the msg about x10 eth deleted, but some people curse:**
[image]
**Also on Twitter i Leave a message to Asked etc:**
[image]
**but my account was frozen after some time. . .
I am very surprised, why official etc Twitter have such a thing?
I do not know the loss can recover? the loss can recover ...? recover...? Are there more people fooled? etc eth to leave more people a bad impression?**

**The cheat website is based on github : https://github.com/etherscanio/etherscanio.github.io
Maybe github should response for it too?**

**i found the info@ethereum.org email on the officail website https://www.ethereum.org/ ,
but email send failed as said not a valid address . And after a long time google , i cant find the email to etc**

Answer (score 1):

The Twitter account you responded to was nothing to do with Ethereum or Ethereum Classic. You sent your money to fraudsters.

In theory it is just possible that they will decide to return the money, or that the police will catch them and make them return the money. But this is very unlikely. Unfortunately your money is gone, and you will not be getting it back.

Comment: if so，the eth and etc org has no responsibility to request twitter to close these fraud accounts? the twitter itself has no responsibility to punish the fraud accounts? why my twitter is frozen by twitter? there is an old world in chinese,路见不平拔刀相助，hope to get more heip and hope eth etc  twitter github can take more responsibility as a Influential  company

Comment: Generally people running non-fraudulent accounts are reporting them, but the fraudsters just create new ones.

The Twitter complaints process doesn't seem good, but it's a difficult problem, because any attempt to close accounts based on complaints is also exploited by fraudsters...

Comment: but if etc or eth or twitter or github do nothing, more people will damaged from the fraud. so we only watch the innocent people go to pic and watch the fraudsters get away with impunity? if you can forward this to you twitter or blog, it will help too. what's more, i registe a new twitter account, and found that it's just the official etc twitter account. i found the etc twitter just from their official website https://ethereumclassic.github.io/ . and their still do nothing.

Comment: It's generally not the official account that's tweeting the fraud, it's a different account replying to that one, with a subtly different name.

Comment: yes,seems true. but at least the gihub can rm the cheat website https://github.com/etherscanio/etherscanio.github.io , or try to find out who owns it . and can eth find out the cheat eth account and do some pulish？thank you for you patient. by the way, which country you are? im china